# NameError: name 'hello_world' is not defined

Tags: django, django-views, nameerror

Using pycharm community  python3.6.2 Django 2.0.3

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello_world(request):  
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views, hello_world),

]
```

i Tried to figure it out but missing something.

error while running on pycharm

> urls.py", line 8, in 
>         url(r'^$', views, hello_world),
>
> NameError: name 'hello_world' is not defined

Comment: can you show me your urls.py ?

Comment: Based on the way you imported `views` in your `urls.py`, you should be calling `hello_world` with `views.hello_world`. Or, you could import views like this instead: `from views import *`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is no variable such as `hello_world` defined. You need to change it to:

```
url(r'^$', views.hello_world)
```

Where `views` is the views module that you have imported at the top.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is wrong

```
url(r'^$', views, hello_world)
```

You just imported the `view` which is the file view.py. Now you need to call the function view, which it is going to be like:

```
url(r'^$', views.hello_world)
```

And you might think it is going to be useful to give that url a name so you can use it as a reference in your templates in the future.

```
url(r'^$', views.hello_world, name='hello-world')
```

Also, you can import your view.py as follow:

```
from .views import hello_world
```

The next is possible as well as suggested in the comments Niayesh Isky, but not encouraged.

```
from .views import *
```